# Responsive design with Twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented responsive design using twitter bootstrap for my site.  The collapsing nav bar works well on phones but not on tablets and ipads.  Basically i would like the collasible nav to automatically be implemented on a tablet or ipad.  i'm finding the bootstrap documentation a little confusing.  can anyone offer some guidance please.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap doesn't work by device, it uses screen widths (via CSS media queries) to collapse the navbar at particular widths. So the only way to enable it by default on the iPad is to make sure it collapses at or above the screen width of the iPad (768px in portrait mode).

I've done the same in the past, and on several occasions ended up editing the `@media` queries that form part of `bootstrap-responsive.css` to get it collapsing for tablets at more suitable widths. Eg:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
```

As detailed [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables), a more progressive method is to customise bootstrap to suit your needs and use custom variables - alter the `@navbarCollapseWidth` variable listed on the page, but you might prefer to edit your width's manually...

On a side note, it's probably worth looking at the screen-widths for various popular tablets and devices. This may be of help: [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)